# Magento2 product import pragmatically i want skip images if not present on csv?

Tags: php, magento, magento2.2

I am trying to upload product pragmatically through CSV all script run well but i have only 1 issue  i have 3 column of  images in my  CSV  1st images are available but in 2nd and 3rd column some images are missing  name are present but images are not found in directory but when i run script only one images are save rest of present images are not saved

My Code is

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
include('app/bootstrap.php');
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$objectManager1 = Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$directoryList = $objectManager1->get('\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList');
$path = $directoryList->getPath('media');

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
$myarray = glob("test.csv"); 
usort($myarray, create_function('$a,$b', 'return filemtime($a) - filemtime($b);'));
if(count($myarray)){

    $csv_map = array_map('str_getcsv', file($myarray[count($myarray)-1]));
    array_walk($csv_map, function(&$a) use ($csv_map) {
      $a = array_combine($csv_map[0], $a);
    });
    array_shift($csv_map); 

    $message = '';
    $count   = 1;
    foreach($csv_map as $data){ 
        //echo '<pre>';print_r($data);exit;

$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
$product->setName(trim($data['NAME']));
$product->setTypeId('simple');
$product->setAttributeSetId(4);
$product->setSku(trim($data['MODEL NUMBER']));
$product->setUrlPath(trim($data['url']).trim($data['MODEL NUMBER']).('zenith'));
$product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));
$product->setVisibility(4);
$product->setBrand(trim($data['BRAND']));
$product->setFunctions(trim($data['FUNCTIONS']));
$product->setPowerReserve(trim($data['POWER RESERVE']));
$product->setStrapType(trim($data['STRAP TYPE']));
$product->setWarranty(trim($data['WARRANTY']));
$product->setFamily(trim($data['FAMILY']));
$product->setWaterResistance(trim($data['WATER RESISTANCE']));
$product->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now'));
$product->setPrice(trim($data['PRICE']));
$product->setcaseSize(trim($data['CASE SIZE']));
//$product->setColor(trim($data['dial_colour']));
$product->setMovement(trim($data['MOVEMENT']));
$product->setCaseShape(trim($data['CASE SHAPE']));
//$product->setGender(trim($data['gender']));
$product->setCaseMaterial(trim($data['CASE MATERIAL']));



//$_product->setShortDescription(trim($data['Short Description'])); // add text attribute
//$_product->setDescription(trim($data['Long Description'])); // add text attribute
 $img_url = trim($data['IMAGE1']);
 $img_url1=trim($data['IMAGE2']);
 $img_url2=trim($data['IMAGE3']);


                $dir = $directoryList->getPath('media').'/big/';
                $imgpath = $dir.$img_url;

                $imgpath1 = $dir.$img_url1;

                $imgpath2 = $dir.$img_url2;
                $product->addImageToMediaGallery($imgpath, array('image'), false, false);

                 if (file_exists($dir.$img_url1)) {

                $product->addImageToMediaGallery($imgpath1, array('thumbnail'), false, false);

                 }

                 if (file_exists($dir.$img_url2)) {

                $product->addImageToMediaGallery($imgpath2, array('small_image'), false, false);

}



$product->setStockData(array(
        'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, //'Use config settings' checkbox
        'manage_stock' => 1, //manage stock
        'min_sale_qty' => 1, //Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
        'max_sale_qty' => 2, //Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
        'is_in_stock' => 1, //Stock Availability
        'qty' => 100 //qty
        )
    );

$product->save();

    }
echo'sucess';
    }
?>
```

please suggest what i am doing wrong in image section

Answer (score 0):

Check the image existence By 
@exif_imagetype($image_path). 
Thank you